# An array of pointers that point to the same array

Tags: delphi, pascal

I've read a piece of Delphi code like this :

```
sample1  = ARRAY[1..80] OF INTEGER; 
psample =^sample1;

VAR
  function :ARRAY[1..70] OF psample;
```

From my understanding, the programmer is trying to declare an array that contains 70 pointers and each pointer points to a sample1 array.

So when I write :

```
function[1]^[1] := 5;
function[1]^[2] := 10;
```

then :

```
function[n]^[1] := 5 
function[n]^[2] := 10; ( n = 2 to 70)
```

Is that correct ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code sample is lacking some information since you do not say how `function` is defined. This means that you cannot draw the conclusions that you attempt to draw.

Of course, since `function` is a reserved word in Pascal, that code could never even compile. I will assume now that the variable is called `f`.

Consider the following definitions:

```
type
  sample1 = array [1..80] of integer; 
  psample = ^sample1;

var
  f : array [1..70] of psample;
```

Here, `sample1` and `psample` are types. `sample1` is type describing an array of 80 integers. `psample` is a pointer to a `sample1`.

Next a variable named `f` is defined. It is an array of 70 `psample`s.

Now, before you can even consider what happens when you write `f[1]^[1]`, we need to assign some values to the elements of `f`.

Suppose we did it like this:

```
var
  sample: sample1;
...
for i := 1 to 70 do
  f[i] := @sample;
```

Now it would be true that `f[i]^[k]` refers to the same integer as `f[j]^[k]` for all valid `i` and `j`. So when you write `f[1]^[1] := 42` you are also assigning that value to `f[2]^[1]`, `f[3]^[1]` and so on.

On the other hand you could do it like this:

```
var
  samples: array [1..70] of sample1;
...
for i := 1 to 70 do
  f[i] := @samples[i];
```

Now each `f[i]` pointer points to a distinct array in memory. In this case assigning `f[1]^[1] := 42` does not modify the value of `f[2]^[1]` or any of the other values.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. You have 70 pointers, each pointing to an array of 80 integers.

Comment: You didn't answer the second part of the question.